# MPMediaPickerController done button missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller

I am facing the done button issue in the MPMediaPickerController.

```
Device: iPod Touch

iOS :9.2   

 MPMediaPickerController  *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];


picker.delegate                     = self;
picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = YES;
picker.showsCloudItems = NO;
picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");

// The media item picker uses the default UI style, so it needs a default-style
//      status bar to match it visually
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The picker is presenting but the done button is missing in the picker. Incase if I click at the place where we have done button earlier the picker is dismissing.
Thank you for spending time for reading my question. Any ideas/suggestion could be very helpful.

Comment: What's your view controller hierarchy? Do you use UIAppearance to manipulate the style of anything? If you enter the view debugger, can you see the button and check its attributes?

Comment: I have taken one rootview controller and I am presenting on it. I am not using any UIAppearance for any manipulation.Thank you

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Can you provide a minimal project that illustrates the issue?

Comment: ok sorry could you please try my code on iOS device 9.2? Just simply created one project and in rootviewcontroller I have written the above code on button action

Comment: That's what I did, and I see the Done button. I tested on simulator only, though.

Comment: I am sorry @jcaron your question Do you use UIAppearance to manipulate the style of anything? really made me thinking about the UIAppearance. Sorry it is a large project and I have searched keyword UIAppearance in my project but didn't find any. After rereading your comment I have searched for appearance. Now I found one line in my project. That was the issue. Thank you so much

Comment: I added it as an answer, feel free to up vote and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that the appearance of the button was changed through UIAppearance.

For people stumbling on the same issue, check for the presence of `appearance`, `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` or `appearanceForTraitCollection:` in the project.

Comment: Thank you @jcaron. I have marked your answer as correct answer.:)